# Possible without String?

Tags: java, string, boolean, conditional-operator

I can’t solve this task without a string (don’t know yet) :

"My program asks the user if he wants to see a smiley. If he answers with 'Y' he gets a ":)", other input will be a ":(". Use a conditional operator."

My solution (with a string):

```
System.out.println("Do you want to see a smiley");
answer=scan.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);

string=(answer=='Y')?: ":)" : ":(";  //works like that but I need it without string
System.out.println(string);
```

btw: is the conditional operator often used?

Thanks for your help
And if there are any further advices tell me please.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use strings?

Comment: "btw: is the conditional operator often used?" yes definitely. "possible without a string" what do you mean?

Comment: like `System.out.println((answer=='Y')?: ":)" : ":(")`? yes, conditional is used often.

Comment: Your conditional operator needn’t return a String - instead just the char value ‘)’ or ‘(‘

Comment: @Serge thank you works fine

Comment: Your `?:` should just be `?`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if i understan you but you can try:

```
if(answer=='Y'){
System.out.println(":)");
}
else{
System.out.println(":(");
}
```

And yes conditional operator for example: if/else is one of the basic things in programing.

Comment: Thats how I normaly used to do it. But I should do it without a if else operation. Sorry didnt mention that!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean without `String` variables? Then here is the nasty oneliner:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to see a smiley");
System.out.println(scan.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0)=='Y' ? ":)" : ":(" );
```

If you mean without using any kind of string (not even ""), you cold print each char individually. This would not require a `String` but is really annoying and unnecessary.

Edit: because requested, here is this version:

```
System.out.print('D');
System.out.print('o');
....
System.out.print('y');
System.out.print('\n');

if (scan.findWithinHorizon(".",0) == 'Y') {
     System.out.print(':');
     System.out.print(')');
     System.out.print('\n');
} else {
     ....
}
```

Comment: thanks. Well I learn with a book at the moment and it didnt tell me yet what a string does. So i have to print it out otherwise i guess.

Comment: btw what do you mean with each char individually? Can you type a code for me?^^